# Run time error in ASP.Net 1.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-1.1

I am using Windows 2003. I have mapped a web application into a virtual directory. This is built on framework 1.1 When i try to browse to the default page i get a error as

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Access is denied: 'Interop.MSDASC'.

Source Error:

Line 196:               
Line 197:               
Line 198:               
Line 199:           
Line 200:

Source File: c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\Config\machine.config    Line: 198

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Interop.MSDASC' could not be loaded.

Comment: Try phrasing your question in such a way that we know what help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 198 of the standard machine.Config contains the line:

```
            <add assembly="*"/>
```

which I assume is loading all assemblies from your local bin directory.  It seems this directory contains an assembly Interop.MSDASC, and that IIS is unable to load this  assembly because of an "Access Denied" error.

Some things to check:

- does the account under which your web app is running (by default the Network Service account) have permission to access this file.
- does your web app really need this assembly?  AFAIK tt's for the Microsoft Data Link API, which allows the app to prompt the user for OLEDB connection information - I don't see why you'd use this in a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts...

Is the Interop.MSDASC dll in your web apps bin folder? Is the com components that this interop library uses installed on this machine?
Are there any funky things going on with permissions for these files?

Good luck, sounds like a nasty one.